# Vlookup + indexOf to find values in a CSV via Google App Script without using loop

Tags: google-apps-script

The main idea is not to need looping to generate a `VLOOKUP` because it generates a huge slowdown when the amount of data is very large.

To VLOOKUP on data directly in the sheet I do as follows:

```
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();     
  var searchValue = s.getRange("Test!A1").getValue();
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXXXXXXXXXXX").getSheetByName("Test 2");
  var dataValues = data.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var dataList = dataValues.join("ღ").split("ღ");
  var index = dataList.indexOf(searchValue);
  
  if (index === -1) {
    s.getRange("Test!B1").setValue('off');
  } else {
    var row = index + 1;
    var foundValue = data.getRange("D"+row).getValue();
    s.getRange("Test!B1").setValue(foundValue);
  }
}
```

But there is a big problem in this method, because when many different accounts try to access this sheet at the same time, the error `type error: could not connect sheet xxxxx` appears or causes huge delay sometimes.

So what was the solution I found? Publish spreadsheet pages as CSV so they can be used and this error doesn't happen when many accounts call the same spreadsheet.

Currently, as I haven't found a way to use `indexOf` using the first column when I import the CSV with several columns of data, I had to create a spreadsheet page only with the copy data of column A, and then I got to the final result of `VLOOKUP` like this:

(the value in `var searchValue` in this example case will be `two`)

```
function myFunction() {
  var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();

  var url_columnA = 'AAAAA';
  var url_vlookup = 'BBBBB';
  
  var dataSearch = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_columnA));
  var dataList = dataSearch.join("ღ").split("ღ");
  var searchValue = s.getRange("Test!A1").getValue();
  var index = dataList.indexOf(searchValue);

  if (index === -1) {
    s.getRange("Test!B1").setValue('off');
  } else {
    var row = index;
    var dataVlookup = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_vlookup));
    var foundValue = dataVlookup[row][3];
    s.getRange("Test!B1").setValue(foundValue);
  }
}
```

Return example:

```
other number
```

`var url_vlookup`:

| Col A | Col B | Col C | Col D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| home | 1 | a | win |
| away | 2 | b | loose |
| one | 3 | c | number |
| two | 4 | d | other number |
| three | 5 | e | number again? |

`var url_columnA`:

| Col A |
| --- |
| home |
| away |
| one |
| two |
| three |

Is there any way to handle `var url_vlookup` data for search the value in column A so that it's not necessary to use this page `var url_columnA` separated or is the only way to do it without looping?

Comment: These appear to be spreadsheets, why not use SpreadsheetApp.openById()?  getValues()? and then Array.find()?  Would be much easier and faster.

Comment: Hi @TheWizEd This is one problem, there will be several clients using triggers calling the same sheet, when I tried to do this, errors appeared when accessing the sheet when many triggers were activated at the same time or it generated a huge slowness. So, I'll have to do it via CSV that doesn't generate this error problem for several simultaneous accesses to the same data.

Comment: importing the data to a clean spreadsheet file wouldn't work for you?

Comment: Hi @DavidSalomon No, because the data from the original sheet is updated every 5 minutes and when many accounts try to access this new sheet, it would give the same problem of many simultaneous accesses that cause errors such as "could not access worksheet xxxxx"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first column can easily be separated after parsing using [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const dataVlookup = Utilities.parseCsv(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url_vlookup));
const url_columnA = dataVlookup.map(row => row[0])
```